# Estimating the Binomial parameter $n$ ( sample size)

Tags: statistical-inference

What will happen if the sample mean exceeds the sample variance ?

I tried to find the answer but all answers gave me the different low between two means.

Could anyone help me to find the best answer. Thanks

Comment: sorry I made mistake in my writing. if the sample mean exceed the sample variance

Comment: I have made corrections. Do you agree with them ?